# Error: "Untrusted application launcher" for desktop-shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, file-properties

I got a new pc with ubuntu 14.04 today and I'm struggling with creating desktop shortcuts.
I wanted libreoffice as shortcut, went to urs/share/applications, copied it and pasted on desktop. But if I try to run it I get the error "Untrusted Application Launcher". I wanted to change properties, but since root is the owner (ridiculous for such a program btw.) I can't do it.
I would appreciate your advice.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You do not say which version of Ubuntu you are using.

However on most systems, if you can find the program in the dash (the equivalent of the Microsoft Windows start menu ), it should just be a case of right clicking the relevant icon and choosing 'Add to desktop'

Sometimes (on Xubuntu for example) the first time you launch the desktop icon, you will get a one time message asking if you wish to make the file executable.Root access should not be required.

Comment: Ohh sorry, it's 14.04 I think.

Comment: Right clicking didnt work or I'm doing it wrong, it just gives the options to launch or uninstall the application.

Comment: I was wrong, I forgot about Ubuntu 14.04. For that system, all you need to do is open the dash by clicking on the Ubuntu symbol (by default on my system it is on the top left), search for the relevant program.When the icon appears below, just left click and drag and drop the icon onto the desktop. I have just tested it with a live usb version of Ubuntu 14.04 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your *.desktop file is lacking execute permissions. Normally that can be fixed with

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/MyProblemShortcut.desktop
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/MyProblemShortcut.desktop
```

Of course, you must substitute the appropriate filename instead of "MyProblemShortcut".

Comment: you should not use `sudo` within your own home unless you already messed up and created a file which belongs to root. And on 17.10 you will get confronted with the trust dialog no matter if you made it executable which is of course needed.